# EXTRACT() Function formatting

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using extract function in my SQL statement. Here is my code

```
->select('EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM value) AS value,  EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM value) AS text')
```

Is show like this "201706" I want to format it like this "2017-06"

Comment: Why are you using `YEAR_MONTH` in one `EXTRACT` but not in the other?

Comment: updated my query

Comment: And forgot the `date_format()`

Comment: This dont work i tried

date_format(value, '%Y-%m') AS text

Comment: I've voted to close as unclear because there have been too many edits done to the question. You appear to be using some type of framework also, CI possibly.

Comment: im using joomla

Comment: Rhea please add all frameworks you use into your tags. It will steer people who don't use that framework away and attract people who *do* use the framework

Answer (score 4):

If you want to format a date value in some particular way, use `DATE_FORMAT()`:

```
select date_format(<value>, '%Y-%m')
```

`EXTRACT()` returns an integer, so it cannot return a value with a hyphen.  You need for the return value to be a string.

Comment: i have updated my question.  i have tried your solution but cant use it like that

Comment: @RheaLorraine . . . I cannot fathom why you would be able to use `extract()` but not `date_format()`.